# Simple HTML DOM working localhost but not in hosted server (managed via cPanel)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to do a web scraping with php and I found the "simple html dom" library.

On localhost it's working perfectly, but when I put it on the server it doesn't work.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);
return $html;
```

I've seen the server settings, php version, but everything ok.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't help you, based on simply staring at some code which works in one environment but not another, with no other information - usually the code itself is not the issue, it'll be some difference in the environments. First do some [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) and identify a clear problem where the code starts to deviate from what you expected it to do. And make sure you check the PHP error log file for any problems, too. See also [ask] for general guidance. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: And since you're using cURL, make sure your hosting provider doesn't block outgoing HTTP requests, and use things like [curl_error]() to check if an issue occurred, check the raw content of $response, and if necessary to verbose [curl-specific debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl) to determine what is happening, if you find that the $response doesn't contain what you were expecting.